# Is the derivative directional?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives

I was met with a surprising face when I assumed that a derivative is a directional change, i.e. that $$\frac{df(x)}{dx}$$

describes the change in $f(x)$ following an *positive* change in $x$. Moreover, the negative derivative describes the change in $f(x)$ following a *negative* change in $x$:

$$-\frac{df(x)}{dx}$$

Am I mistaken?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course since the derivative

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}$$

represent the rate of change of $f(x)$ for a positive change of $x$ (i.e. for $x$ increasing) then

$$-\frac{df(x)}{dx}$$

represent the rate of change of $f(x)$ for negative change of $x$ (i.e. for $x$ decreasing).

Observe that the term directional derivative is used when we deal with several variables, in this case for any $\vec v=(a,b)$ we can define the **directional derivative** as:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec v}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+ah,y_0+bh)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$$

Notably the partial derivatives are the directional derivatives corresponding to the unit vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Moreover, wheter $f$ is differentiable the following holds:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec v}=\nabla f\cdot\vec v=v_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+v_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful with statements like $-\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ being the change in $f(x)$ following a *negative* change in $x$

Take for example $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=3$ so $f(x)=9$.  Then $\frac{df(x)}{dx}=2x$ which is $6$ when $x=3$.

A small positive change in $x$ changes $f(x)$ by about the change multiplied by $6$: so for example $f(3+0.01) = 3.01^2= 9.0601$ which is close to $f(3) + 0.01 \times 6$

A small negative change in $x$ also changes $f(x)$ by about the change multiplied by $6$: so for example $f(3-0.01) = 2.99^2= 8.9401$ which is close to $f(3) - 0.01 \times 6$. And it is safer to think of it this way than think of the result being something like $f(3) + 0.01 \times (-6)$.

In other words, keeping the sign of the change means you do not need to reverse the sign of the derivative

Comment: Thanks. Could you see my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2672727/function-value-change-with-constrained-arguments I think you could probably answer it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  it is directional. The same way that when we say that a function is "increasing", we are seeing it from left to right.